# How to undo log transformation after prediction in R?

Tags: r, transform

I've applied multivariate linear regression to my logarithmic transformed dependent feature. Four of the 30 independent features are also log transformed.  I want to undo the log transformation after the prediction, however, because it would be easier to interpret the RMSE and MAE scores when the features are not log transformed. I can't seem to figure out how this works however.

This is how the code for the model looks like:

```
m1 <- lm(Feature.logtransformed ~., data = trainset)
```

And this is the code I'm using to obtain the RMSE score of my model:

```
rmse <- function(model){
  y = trainset$Feature.logtransformed
  y.pred = predict(model, trainset) 
  return(sqrt(mean((y - y.pred)^2)))
}

rmse(m1)
```

I thought of doing something like this:

```
rmset <- function(model){
  y = trainset$Feature.logtransformed
  y = y - exp(y)
  y.pred = predict(model, trainset)
  return(sqrt(mean((y - y.pred)^2)))
}
```

I used this code to transform the features:

```
df$Feature.logtransformed <- log(df$Feature.logtransformed + 1 )
```

But this does not seem to give good results? If anyone could help, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
rmset <- function(model){
y = trainset$Feature.logtransformed
y.pred = predict(model, trainset)

y<-exp(y) - 1
y.pred<-exp(y.pred)-1

return(sqrt(mean((y - y.pred)^2)))
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I get the right results now! Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Bryan y.pred should actually be exp(y.pred) - 1 , isn't it ?